# Click and trigger a function on table generated by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My page has ajax function which generate table and attache it to a div.
Following is the php page called by Ajax.

```
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='12' cellpadding='4' style='border-collapse: collapse' width='700' id='tablecat'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $category = $row['category'];

echo "<tr bgcolor='white'>
<td class='value'>$category</td>
</tr>";
}

echo  "</table>";
```

Then I need to call another ajax call when the table cells are clicked. Tried many ways but no success.

```
$("#tablecat").on("click", "td", function() {

});
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: put your next ajax call in the code above. whats the problem in that ?

Comment: is your code inside $(document).ready()

Comment: Resolved by Norlihazmey Ghazali's answer. I have marked it as the correct answer. Next problem facing is how can I read a value in this ajax loaded content?  document.getElementById('abcd').value not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `event delegation` did't work in this case because `$("#tablecat")` also created dynamically, you need to reference on its top level like the `div` that hold the `table` or the `body` or `document` like so:

```
$(document).on("click","#tablecat td", function() {
     alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear that and you're welcome, consider accept the answer by clicking the `right mark` on left side of this answer for letter references.

Comment: One more help. can you please tell me how to read the text in this ajax generated table cell? in my code the value of $category ? something like document.getElementById('abcd').value not working.

Comment: If you mean this line of code `<td class='value'>$category</td>`, called it by `$(this).text()`, since the selector already targeted `"#tablecat td"`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you write your event listener on document ready, but as listener setted to object which not exists on document ready (it gets by ajax) it does not work.

You can set listener on body, for example:

```
$("body").on("click", "#tablecat tr td", function(e) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know one option, you can you the jQuery code inside AJAX success function.
For an example:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/fielname.php", 
type: "POST", //POST
success:function(response) {
    $("#tablecat").on("click", "td", function() {

    });
},
error:function(data){

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set

```
$("#tablecat").on("click", "td", function() { 

});
```

in a function and when you generate table with ajax, on success - call this function.